# Using the same jQuery functions but causing conflicts in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Title** - Sorry about the title, it was difficult for me to actually explain this.

So I recently finished working on a dynamic fields system using jQuery. This is all working great however I'm wanting to re-use the html for the system over and over again on the same page, this causes problems.

**Problem**
- When you have duplicates of the form on the same page, and you press 'Add Field' it will run the function and apply the functions to the other classes on the page. (See fiddle for example.)

When you just have one form on the DOM it works fine, but I'm wanting to alter the html slightly so I can use it for different scenarios on a page. I don't want to have separate jQuery files to do this because I don't think it's necessary. I was thinking maybe I could target it's parent containers instead of the class directly? Then I could recycle the same code maybe?

Any suggestions on this guys?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1">
        <input type="button" class="duplicate" value="duplicate">
        <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove">
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line'),
        removing = false;

    $('.remove').hide();

    $('.add').click(function () {
        var newElement = blank_line.clone(true).hide();
        $('form').append(newElement);
        $(newElement).slideDown();
        $('.remove').show();
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
        $(this).parent().clone().hide().insertAfter($(this).parent().after()).slideDown();
        $('.input_line').last().before($('.add'));
        $('.remove').show();
        input = input + 1;
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.remove', function () {
        if (removing) {
            return;
        } else {
            if ($('.input_line').length <= 2) {
                $('.remove').hide();
            }
            $(this).parent().slideUp(function () {
                $(this).remove();
                removing = false;
            });
            $('.input_line').last().before($('.add'));
            input = input - 1;
        }
        removing = true;
    });
});
```

**Working fiddle** - **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95vaaxsL/1/)**

**Problem fiddle** - **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95vaaxsL/)**

As you can see in the problem fiddle above, when you duplicate the form it start conflicting. I would like each form to work independently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're probably going to want to use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Could you perhaps demonstrate this in a fiddle?

Comment: Please don't use "you" when describing a problem, it can be a source of frustration to many readers. Use "I" or passive voice instead.

Comment: I made your fiddle's "Add Fields" buttons work using `closest()`: http://jsfiddle.net/95vaaxsL/2/.

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to note that down when asking a question in the future. Would you mind explaining how exactly this is working, I noticed you added `eq(0)` on line 4 which I have never seen before?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read up on the documentation. Also the comment you provided only works for the 'Add Field' button, would you mind updating your fiddle to include the 'duplicate' & 'remove' buttons too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use closest('form') to find the associated form.  Also when looking up the other fields, you need to search within the context of the related form,  http://jsfiddle.net/95vaaxsL/7/

```
function addLine($inputLine) {
    var $form = $inputLine.closest('form');
    var $newElement = $inputLine.clone(true).hide();

    $newElement.insertAfter($inputLine);
    $newElement.slideDown();
    $form.find('.remove').show();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('.remove').hide();

    $('.add').click(function () {
        addLine($(this).closest('form').find('.input_line:last'));
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
        addLine($(this).closest('.input_line'));
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.remove', function () {
        var $inputLine = $(this).closest('.input_line');
        var $form = $inputLine.closest('form');

        if ($form.find('.input_line').length < 3) {
            $form.find('.remove').hide();
        }

        $inputLine.slideUp(function(){
            $inputLine.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Pulled out the function.

Comment: This seems to add two input_lines at a time now?

Comment: For the most part this seem to be working, apart from the remove button. If you check my working fiddle you cannot remove the first input but this feature seems to be dialled with your edits to the code?

Comment: Yeah, a lot of funkiness haha

Comment: Also, with the changes you have made, when you spam the 'remove' button you can remove all elements. On my working fiddle you couldn't do this.

Comment: Spamming still an issue?  There is a 7, but it was minor refactoring.

Comment: did you update the fiddle? It was an issue with fiddle 6

Comment: Just been testing fiddle 7 and there still seems to be issues with spamming, try adding a bunch of fields then spam removing them, the spam add them, then spam remove them. After doing that a couple of times it seems to break pretty easily :/

Comment: Will have to tinker tomorrow.  Haven't quite gotten my finger on the last issue.

Comment: Alrite, thanks for the help so far, looking forward to your response tomorrow! :-)